# two table, One is tag_t which containing tagName and other is book_t. when I will add new tag to tag_t then I want a to add new column in book_t

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Database scheme:

[image]

If i create a new tag then `book_table` create a new column automatically.

Is it possible?

Comment: That seems like a *horrible* idea to do that. Is it possible? You could probably get something working. That will require a DDL ALTER TABLE statement to be executed on `book_table`, and that's going to be expensive in terms of concurrency (exclusive locks), and resources (creating a new copy of the table).  What are you going to do when the number of rows in `tag_t` exceeds the number of columns allowed in a table? When a row is deleted? Updated?  It's a *horrible* idea. The normal relational approach is an additional relationship table, with foreign key references to `book` and `tag`.

Comment: tag_table:

 id  tagName
1     history
2     Science
 book_table:

 id     tagName_1   taName_2 tagName_---
1         1           0        1
2         0           1        1
Is it possible for book_table toenter image description heretag_table if i create a new column automatically when I tag then book_table create a new tag column automatically. is it possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a relationship table instead.

```
CREATE TABLE book_tag_t
( book_id   INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
, tag_id    INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (book_id,tag_id)
, CONSTRAINT book_tag_t_book FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES book_t (id)
     ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
, CONSTRAINT book_tag_t_tag FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tag_t (id)
     ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

To relate a `tag`\ to a \`book`

```
INSERT INTO book_tag_t (book_id, tag_id) VALUES ( 2, 14 );
```

To get all of the books related to a specific tag:

```
SELECT b.id
  FROM book_t b
  JOIN book_tag_t r
    ON r.book_id = b.id
  JOIN tag_t t
    ON t.id = r.tag_id
 WHERE t.tagName = 'Science' 
 ORDER BY b.id
```

---

To address the question you asked, "Is it possible?"

You could probably get something working. That will require a DDL ALTER TABLE statement to be executed on book_table, and that's going to be expensive in terms of concurrency (exclusive locks), and resources (creating a new copy of the table). And you can't do an ALTER TABLE in a trigger. If you actually *need* functionality like this, the required SQL would be better executed from the application, not from something "automatic" in the database.

What are you going to do when the number of rows in `tag_t` exceeds the number of columns allowed in a table? When a row is deleted? or updated?

It's a horrible idea.

The normal relational approach is to add a third table, a relationship table, to resolve the many-to-many relationship between `book` and `tag`. As illustrated in the first part of this answer.

Comment: This is 10000x better than creating new column if any new rows inserted. You can even restrict its relationship if you aware something gonna happen between two

Comment: Does this task  have any way without relationship??

Comment: @SalmanQuader: design for relational databases usually starts with an Entity Relationship Model that specifies the entities (person,place,thing,concept or even that can be uniquely identified, is important to the business, and that we need to store information about)... and the relationships between those entities. And then based on the logical model, we can propose a physical implementation of the database and the transactions. If you don't have any relationships between entities, then your use-case probably doesn't need a relational database at all.